# c++ delete pointer of a derived class which is assigned to a pointer of the base class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

I have following code:

```
/* Example OOPBEI03.CPP  */
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef char item;

class stack
{
private:
    int p;
protected:
    item *st;
public:
    stack(int m=100)
    {
        st = new item[m];
        p = 0;
    }

    ~stack()
    {
        delete [] st;
    }

    void push(item v)
    {
        st[p++] = v;
    }

    item pop()
    {
        return st[--p];
    }

    int empty()
    {
        return !p;
    }
};

class queue : public stack
{
private:
    int q;
    item *qp;
public:
    queue(int m=50):stack(m)
    {
        q = 0;
        qp = st;
    }

    ~queue()
    {
        delete qp;
    }

    item deque()
    {
        return qp[q++];
    }
};

int main()
{
    stack s(50);
    queue q(20);

    s.push('a');
    q.push('b');
    s.push('c');
    q.push('d');

    cout<<"pop   "<<s.pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"pop   "<<s.pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"deque "<<q.deque()<<endl;
    cout<<"deque "<<q.deque()<<endl;
    cout<<"empty queue? "<<q.empty()<<endl;
    cout<<"empty stack? "<<s.empty()<<endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get at the end of main() in Visual Studio following error: "Debug Assertion Failed! ... _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)".

If I uncomment the delete operation either in the destructor of the class queue or stack (I uncomment only one operation!), I have no problems.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't see the rule of three/five being followed.

Comment: First read about `virtual` destructors, then about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and finally think about what happens when you attempt to free a pointer twice.

Comment: @all: Thank you for your answers. The problem is, that this code is in my learning book. I'm learning C++ in school right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `qp` should me the same as newing (it's term of mine))).

```
delete [] qp;
       ^^
```

But in this particular case deleting `qp` should be removed at all

Comment: the `delete[]` in class `stack` appears to already be of this form.

Answer (score 1):

you're deleting the pointer both in the stack base class and in the queue derived class.

let your stack class handle the ownership, don't delete it also in queue

by the way you should make copy construction and copy assignment private, or else handle it (known as the "rule of three"); otherwise these classes can easily be used in ungood ways...

---

in code that isn't just for learning, just use `std::stack` and `std::queue` instead of implementing such classes yourself

`std::stack` and `std::queue` are class templates with customizable underlying container type

Comment: Actually, only the destructor of queue gets called because stack's constructor is not virtual. It fails because it should use delete [] qp. But I agree that it would be best to make stack's destructor virtual and let it handle the deletion.

Comment: @KristianDuske: how about trying out such things before posting? ;-) not that results with a given compiler are any *guarantee* that that's what the standard mandates, but it's highly suggestive.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Both desctructors get called. I shall make sure my comments are actually correct in the future!